# Bad signs in a department for PhD

Tags: mathematics, university, reputation

Is it a bad sign in a department if most of those who do their thesis in that department also did their undergraduate studies there and most of those who get their PhD there either

1. are employed in said university

or more often than that

2. find themselves outside of academia roughly within 5 years after defense?

EDIT: The department is a European mathematics department. It is mostly focused on teaching. There are (maybe?) roughly 10-20 PhD students. The department has been around from 1959 I think. The country in question has a handful of universities.

Comment: Yes, it is a bad sign.

Comment: Maybe. What country? How many PhD-granting institutions are there in that country? Etc. There may be extenuating circumstances. EU, UK, US/NA, it's probably bad.

Comment: I think it also would depend on the population size. How many PhD students are we talking about? Maybe it is young department mostly focused on education and not on research (which might or might not be a problem depending on circumstances)

Comment: It's good if you want to stay in that city and get a job in that department! If you're motivated to have a highly successful research career then it's likely not so good.

Comment: I live in a small European country where the described situation - academics spending their entire careers at a single university - is the norm. Part of this is because there aren't many national universities and people tend to value social/family life over mobility/prestige. Part of it is a (IMO) dysfunctional system that makes universities focused almost exclusively on undergrad teaching, with research often being secondary (funding problems due to lack of political interest in research don't help). Whether or not this is bad depends on your ambitions and values.

Comment: I teach at a university in the USA where there are several faculty members who received many degrees from the same university. Yes, most of them did venture out and then return to be faculty. One of the main reasons, we see this at my university is because the weather is so darn cold that only those who have been "branded" by the fierce weather for long periods of time and liked it would seem to have the inclination to remain or be back here. This is one of the driving factors, as our hiring data would suggest.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that this is generally a bad sign, especially your number 2, but I would add a "but" to this answer.

When the language used for teaching at the University is not English, situation number 1 can arise. Some department have a hard time recruiting and keeping researchers that are willing to learn a second language and teach in it.

Another way to evaluate the quality of the department would be to look at the collaboration they have with other institutions and the scientific literature they produce (among other things).

Answer (score 4):

In any country with established PhD programs, this is a bad thing. If it was in a country trying to establish a research program, then it is harder to say. There may be extenuating circumstances, but I'd definitely be wary of joining a program like this, without significant research ahead of time.